# Logon to my company's online sharepoint with only a userid and not a password

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I want to use Pnp-PowerShell to access my company's Online SharePoint. But with the logon to my company's Online Sharepoint it only asks for a userid and not a password.

How can i write this in Powershell code. To just logon with a userid and not a password?

Greetings,

P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can store your credentials in Windows Credential manager and use below command to connect SharePoint online.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com
```

below are some of Useful links by which you can connect to SharePoint Online with your credential Manager.

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/wiki/How-to-use-the-Windows-Credential-Manager-to-ease-authentication-with-PnP-PowerShell

https://www.petri.com/managing-usernames-passwords-powershell-sharepoint-online